# How many items are values in dictionaries, Python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm looking to find out how to write the code to see how many values a key has in a dictionary.
For example, I'm doing a small survey on a class to see the colour of eyes, I make a dictionary and put all of their names into the dictionary as strings as values. How do i find out how many people have each colour eyes?

Comment: What have you tried ? (hint : what you're asking for is absolutely trivial...)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. 
While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, 
they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. 
A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, 
example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). 
The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: thanks guys, this was for some help on a CA for uni so I couldn't give the exact code or use it as an example so i just came up with this of the top of my head. I had tried loads of ways but I've managed to solve it now, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

```
survey = {'blue' : ['Kyle', 'Josh', 'Michael']}
len(survey['blue'])
```